# Single() method not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am implementing Table storage in windows azure project. My code:

```
 /// //// Method of _Table class 

    public CloudTableQuery<Html> AccessEntites()
    {
        CloudTableQuery<Html> entries =
            (from e in ServiceContext.CreateQuery<Html>(TableName)
             select e).AsTableServiceQuery();

        return entries;
    }
 /// //                          

 /// Controller code

    private _Table db = new _Table("table-name");

    public ViewResult Details(string id)
    {
        Html htmlfile = db.AccessEntites().Single(h => h.RowKey == id); <=========           
        return View(htmlfile);
    }
 //////
```

Problem here is that i am getting Exception `Single method not supported`. Can anybody tell me why ?

Comment: `using System.Linq` by any chance?

Comment: what is this `_Table` and what `db.AccessEntites()` returns??

Comment: `Linq` and `sql` aren't identical.  Not everything that can be described using `ling` can be translated automatically to `sql`.  When you do something that the computer can't translate you get that message.  (You can substitute `sql` for whatever data provider you are trying to access with `Linq`.)

Comment: I have posted AccessEntites() method also guys, please take a closer look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the LINQ provider for azure table storage doesn't support the `Single` method, i.e. it cannot translate it at runtime to the appropriate query.

Use `FirstOrDefault` instead - https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/#retrieve-single-entity